# Moment of inertia about the origin of an ellipsoid?

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Find the moment of inertia about the origin of an ellipsoid. Heres what I did but I believe it is incorrect:

$$I_o= \iiint_{V_e}{(x^2 +y^2 +z^2)\rho dx dy dz} $$
Making Substitution of $aX=x \ bY=y \ cZ=z
\ and\ dx=adX,  \ dy=bdY, \  dz=cdZ$
$$I_o= abc\iiint_{V_s}{(a^2X^2 +b^2Y^2 +c^2Z^2)\rho dX dY dZ} $$
Now we can change utilize symmetry of sphere that is left to get
$$I_o= abc\iiint_{V_s}{(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)X^2\rho dX dY dZ} $$
$$I_o= \rho abc(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)\iiint_{V_s}{X^2 dX dY dZ} $$
Because of symmetry. Professor told us that $$ \iiint_{V_s}{X^2 dX dY dZ}= {3 \pi \over 15 }$$ (Im not sure how he got this so if someone could explain I would be very grateful

This leaves me with $I_o=\rho abc(a^2 +b^2 +c^2) {3 \pi \over 15 }$

Comment: $\rho$ is density by the way

Comment: What kind of "moment of inertia" is this where you're integrating $r^2$ with $r$ the distance from the origin and not from an axis?

Comment: Just called the moment of inertia about the origin. See http://www.vias.org/calculus/12_multiple_integrals_04_06.html and http://www.math24.net/physical-applications-of-triple-integrals.html

Comment: Interesting -- I studied physics and I never came across this :-) Of your two links, only the second one introduces that concept (and then never seems to use or even mention it again); the first one deals with rotations in two dimensions, where the "moment of inertia about the origin" is identical to the moment of inertia about an axis through the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number you quote is not that integral but its ratio to the volume of the sphere. In polar coordinates:

$$
\int_0^1r^2\mathrm dr\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi \,z^2\\
=\int_0^1r^2\mathrm dr\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi \,r^2\cos^2\theta\\
=\int_0^1r^4\mathrm dr\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\cos^2\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi\\
=2\pi\left[\frac15r^5\right]^1_0\left[\frac13\cos^3\theta\right]^{\cos\theta=1}_{\cos\theta=-1}\\
=\frac{4\pi}{15}
$$

and

$$
\int_0^1r^2\mathrm dr\int_{-1}^1\mathrm d\cos\theta\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm d\phi \\\
=4\pi\left[\frac13r^3\right]^1_0\\
=\frac{4\pi}3\;,
$$

so the ratio is $3\pi/15=\pi/5$. This would be the right number to use if you'd taken out a factor of $m$ instead of a factor of $\rho=m/V$.

Other than that, and the fact that you're writing $V$ for two different volumes (the sphere and the ellipsoid), your approach is correct.

Comment: I believe instead of $3 \pi \over 15$ I meant to put $4 \pi \over 15$, would that make the final answer correct? I not seeing what to do after the step of $$I_o= \rho abc(a^2 +b^2 +c^2)\iiint_{V_s}{X^2 dX dY dZ}$$, Do I switch to spherical and attempt to integrate?

Comment: @user243037: I don't understand the question -- I wrote that integration out for you above -- that's how I got the $4\pi/15$. Yes, if you replace $3\pi/15$ by $4\pi/15$ (or alternatively replace $\rho$ by $m$), your final answer is correct.

Comment: Gotcha, just had to stare at it for a minute. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

Using symmetry, $\iiint_S{X^2 dX dY dZ}=\iiint_S{Z^2 dX dY dZ} $;

and using spherical coordinates with $Z=\rho\cos\phi$ gives

$\iiint_S{Z^2 dX dY dZ}=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^1\rho^2\cos^2\phi\cdot\rho^2\sin\phi d\rho d\phi d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\frac{1}{5}\sin\phi\cos^2\phi d\phi d\theta$

$=\frac{1}{5}\int_0^{2\pi}\big[-\frac{1}{3}\cos^3\phi\big]_0^{\pi}d\theta=\frac{1}{15}\cdot2\cdot2\pi=\frac{4\pi}{15}\;\;$ (instead of $\frac{3\pi}{15}$)